# IntelliJ - How to link modules for maven goal

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have successfully imported a parent pom with child modules into IntelliJ. The child modules have dependencies between themselves and IntelliJ has correctly set up the classpaths so that changes to module A are reflected in module B. However these dependencies are not maintained when I  execute a maven goal in IntelliJ (compile, jetty:run etc). Here is my structure:

```
client_libs
 -- servlet-filter
 -- filter-example
```

filter-example depends on servlet-filter. However when I run maven compile on filter-example I get:

```
The POM for com.cloudseal.client:servlet-filter:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

I can work around this by manually installing servlet-filter into my local repo before I execute a maven goal but obviously this is not ideal. How can I get IntelliJ to maintain the relationships between the modules when I execute a maven goal?

[image: parent pom]

[image: filter example]

[image: project structure]

[image: dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

You shall be able to just run *mvn package* but from place/path where your parent pom is.

If this's not working for you, please post your pom.xml files.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is not a maven one, I can successfully build the project using maven. What I was hoping to do was to see a change made in project A reflected in project B in IntelliJ without having to rebuild all the projects. This already happens within the IDE i.e. if I comment out a method in servlet-filter the IDE immediately complains that filter-example is calling a non-existant method. However if i use IntelliJ to run a maven goal e.g. jetty:run it will work because it's still using the old classes in my local repo.

Comment: Ok, so solution to your problem is JRebel. You can see changes of code automagically in your build application. You can make proper configuration using maven or just install JRebel plugin, create Jetty local configuration and run it with JRebel.